# function replica.erl:90: syntax error before: '.'

Tags: erlang

```
perform(Cmd, Decisions, Slot_out, Database) ->
  {Client, Cid, Op} = Cmd,
  Is_member = lists:member(maps:values(maps:with(lists:seq(1, Slot_out - 1), Decisions)),
  if
    Is_member == true ->
      nothing;
    true ->
 87     Database ! {execute, Op},
 88     Client ! {response, Cid, ok}
 89 end,
 90 Slot_out + 1.
```

In erlang I write a code like this, but it always have an error.

```
90:syntax error before: '.'
```

Anyone know how to solve it? Thank you so much!

Comment: Since @byaruhaf solved your problem, please accept their answer.

I also have an additional suggestion: try the IDEA IDE + Erlang plugin. It will mark for you any such errors without the need to compile. https://github.com/ignatov/intellij-erlang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

missing a closing bracket **")"** on this line

```
Is_member = lists:member(maps:values(maps:with(lists:seq(1, Slot_out - 1), Decisions)),
```

it should be:

```
Is_member = lists:member(maps:values(maps:with(lists:seq(1, Slot_out - 1), Decisions))),
```

Comment: @shadow no worries.